# A pythonic way to solve the following implementation

Tags: django, python, django-orm

I have 3 models in my django app

```
class Company(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(_("Name"), max_length = 100, blank = True, null = True)
    address = models.CharField(_("Address"), max_length = 300, blank = True, null = True)

class WebSite(models.Model):

    WEBSITE_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('Google+', 'Google+'),
        ('Facebook', 'Facebook'),
        ('Orkut', 'Orkut'),
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    website = models.URLField(blank = True, null = True)
    website_type = models.CharField(max_length = 15, choices = WEBSITE_TYPE_CHOICES, default = 'Google+')
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, null=True, blank=True)

class Review(models.Model):

    rating = models.FloatField(blank = True, null = True) 
    review = models.TextField(blank = True, null = True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, null=True, blank=True)
    website = models.ForeignKey(Website, null=True, blank=True)
```

I want to display my data such as

CompanyA:

1. Google - 5 reviews, Avg 3.4
2. Orkut - 9 reviews, Avg 4.1
3. Facebook - 12 reviews, Avg 4.3
4. Anyother - 2 reviews, Avg 2

CompanyB:

1. Google - 2 reviews, Avg 3
2. Facebook - 5 reviews, Avg 4

For this I have done

```
    final_list = company_list = []
    websites = Website.objects.select_related().filter(user = user)

    for website in websites:
        company = website.company
        if company is not None and company not in company_list:
            company_list.append(brand)
            company_websites = websites.filter(company = company)
            info = []
            for company_website in company_websites:
                company_type = company_website.website_type
                reviews = Review.objects.filter(company = company, website = company_website)
                no_of_reviews = len(reviews)
                average = reviews.aggregate(Avg('rating'))
                info.append({"type": company_type, "no_of_reviews": no_of_reviews,
                             "average": average['rating__avg']})
            final_list.append({"company": company.name, "stats": info})
```

**There are 2 problems with the code**

1. It is wasting a lot of computation
2. It also somehow appends empty lists in the final_list (BUGGY)

**FYI:** I believe .annotate() can be used, but I fail to understand how can I use it based on a column, which in my case is (company__name)

Comment: do you want final_list and company_list to be exactly the same?  If not, split the first line into two separate lines.  In Python, variable names for lists end up being pointers to the list elements in memory.  So, in your code, final_list and company_list are both pointing to the same list.

Comment: initially looking for something a bit flexible in the ORM

Comment: I was just making a side comment.  Don't write ... final_list = company_list = [], unless you want them to stay identical.

Comment: I don't see where website.brand is created or what it refers to.

Comment: yes that was an error. Please see now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you the data.

```
Review.objects.values(company, website__website_type).annotate(review_count=Count('id'), average=Avg('rating')).order_by('company')
```

Use [{% regroup %}](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) to output it in template.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this and it's probably not as good as the other answer you've received, but in case it helps ...

```
companies = Company.objects.all()
company_ratings = []

for company in companies:
    websites = company.website_set.filter(user=user)
    new_data = []

    for website in websites:
        reviews = Reviews.objects.filter(website=website, company=company)
        ratings = [x.rating for x in reviews]
        count = len(ratings)
        new_data.append({'website': website, 'count': count, 
                         'average': float(sum(ratings))/count})

    company_ratings.append({'company':company, 'ratings':new_data})
```